# AWS dynamodb PHP 'Command was not found matching Update_table'

Tags: php, fatal-error, amazon-dynamodb

I working on a web application and since a lot of read and write action happening in the amazon dynamodb table am facing a `provisionthroughput` error. Thinking of using a Update table I used below code but facing error. This error is not mentioned in error handling chart of dynamobb.

```
<?php

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

$dynamoDB = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'key' => '', 
    'secret' => '',
    'region' => Region::US_WEST_1
));

####################################################################
# Updating the table
 // $dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo "# Updating the \"${dynamo_db_table}\" table..." . PHP_EOL;

$up = $dynamoDB->Update_table(array(
    'TableName' => $dynamo_db_table,
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => array(
        'ReadCapacityUnits' => 39,
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => 37
    )
));

$table_status = $dynamoDB->describe_table(array(
    'TableName' => $dynamo_db_table
));

// Check for success...
if ($table_status->isOK())
{
    print_r($table_status->body->Table->ProvisionedThroughput->to_array()->getArrayCopy());
}
else
{
    print_r($table_status);
}       

$count = 0;
do {
    sleep(5);
    $count += 5;

    $response = $dynamoDB->describe_table(array(
        'TableName' => $table_name
    ));
}
while ((string) $response->body->Table->TableStatus !== 'ACTIVE');

echo "The table \"${table_name}\" has been updated (slept ${count} seconds)." . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

I am facing below error:

```
# Updating the "tablename" table... 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command was not found matching Update_table' in /home/phretscl/public_html/RETS/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php:117 Stack trace: #0 /home/phretscl/public_html/RETS/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(94): Guzzle\Service\Client->getCommand('Update_table', Array) #1 /home/phretscl/public_html/RETS/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(103): Guzzle\Service\Client->__call('Update_table', Array) #2 /home/phretscl/public_html/RETS/file.php(97): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->__call('Update_table', Array) #3 /home/phretscl/public_html/RETS/file.php(97): Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient->Update_table(Array) #4 {main} thrown in /home/phretscl/public_html/RETS/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on line 117
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is not correct. From the error message, I can tell you are using version 2.x of the AWS SDK for PHP, but the code you using from `############` line down looks like it is meant for version 1.x of the AWS SDK for PHP. The error is being thrown, because you are not calling the [`DynamoDbClient::updateTable()` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_updateTable) correctly.

You should checkout the [AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/index.html), particularly the [page about DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html), which has a code sample for `UpdateTable`.

---

**EDIT w/ regards to the comments**: If this is a long running process, you should use the `Aws\Common\Aws` way of instantiating the client, since it retains and reuses the client objects it creates. Replace you `DynamoDbClient::factory(...)` code with this:

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;

$aws = Aws::factory(array(
    'key' => '...', 
    'secret' => '...',
    'region' => Region::US_WEST_1
));

$dynamoDB = $aws->get('dynamodb');
```

Comment: I ll check it and return to you, until then please wait.

Comment: I replaced `$up = $dynamoDB->Update_table(array('TableName'=>$dynamo_db_table,'ProvisionedThroughput'=>array('ReadCapacityUnits'=> 39,'WriteCapacityUnits'=>37)));` with `$dynamoDB->updateTable(array('TableName' => 'Retslistings','ProvisionedThroughput'=>array('ReadCapacityUnits'=>15,'WriteCapacityUnits' => 25))); ` but a `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/phretscl/public_html/RETS/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Response.php on line 918`

Comment: so no solutions or atleast suggestions from your end.

Comment: I've never seen that error happen or received any other reports for just doing an UpdateTable operation. How big of a server are you using? Is this a long-running process? Any tweaks you can do to your server or php.ini to prevent this?

Comment: The server has a 8GB for RAM. Yes, it's a long running process. I did a memory limit change and execution time change in the php.ini file.

Comment: What does your long running process do? Is this just part of that code then? I just added a note to the answer about potentially using the `Aws\Common\Aws` class to instantiate the client object, which may help with memory consumption. It might also help to periodically call `gc_collect_cycles()` to manually trigger garbage collection to free up memory.

Comment: The long running process does a internet data exchange. Yes it's a part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the credentials like this
Also, the region should be like this 'region'=>'us-east-1'

```
$DDBClient = DynamoDbClient::factory([
                'region'=>'us-east-1',
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                ]
                ,'scheme'  => 'http' // Use this if you don't have HTTPS
                //, 'debug' => true
            ]);
```